# Don't display empty return sets

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following sql code:

```
select 'select * from ' + table_name + ' where ' + column_name + ' = 123'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%columnOfInterest%'
```

For a given database, this looks through all the tables that have a column named `columnOfInterest` which contain a value 123.
This is for debug purposes and so the output doesn't have to be pretty and it certainly is not.
Most of the tables don't have a column and of those even fewer have a value of 123 in them, so most of the return sets are empty.
I'm looking for ways to neaten the output. For example, I don't need to see empty sets at all. Any ideas on how to do this or clean it up otherwise?
Attached is a screenshot of the output in SQL Server Manage. I've had to erase some potentially sensitive column names. The blue columns are the columnOfInterest, the black, all others. Each row you see here is the empty output from 1 table.

[image]

Comment: When you say "*sets*" (in plural). Where do they come from? Is your query a part of a larger script?

Comment: The entire body of code, so to speak, is shown here. The sets come from the fact that it is a `select` within a `select`.

Comment: The code you posted generates a bunch of select statements. Do you copy these statements and then run them and it is that set that you do not want to see if it is blank?

Comment: It's not a nested query. You have a single `SELECT`  statement that produces a string.

Comment: I may very well not have the nomenclature correct as I am at the edge of my understanding of sql here. I've added a screenshot of what I see. hth.

Comment: Depends on the output you required, if you need same format output, you may just add ""IF EXIST()" before SELECT

Comment: you're just building a bunch of strings based on the matching rows, and those strings happen to contain sql. but that generated sql will NOT be executed like this. it's like me writing "I am a gun" here will not magically make me able to fire bullets out of my fingers.

Comment: @MarcB: you are correct. I will post the correct code, probably tomorrow as it is towards the end of the day here. I apologize for wasting people's time with my mistake.

Comment: Actually, its not as bad as I thought. The code is my statement is repeated many times, such that the question can be rephrased to "If that statement returns an empty set, how do I get it to print nothing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the dynamic query in a IF block that tests if the query will return anything.

```
select 'if exists (' + QUERY + ')' + char(10) + '    ' + QUERY
from (
    select QUERY = 'select * from ' + TABLE_NAME 
        + ' where ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = 123'
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
    where COLUMN_NAME like '%columnOfInterest%'
)  q
```

Comment: Query is just the name for the column of your original query

Answer (score 1):

This should return the table names with column name.  Will this do?

```
DECLARE @Tsql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Tsql = ''
select @Tsql = @Tsql +  'select TOP(1) ''' + c.table_schema + '.' + c.table_name + ''' AS TableName, ''' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS ColumnName  from ' + c.table_schema + '.' + c.table_name + ' where EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM ' + c.table_schema + '.' + c.table_name + ' WHERE ' + c.column_name + ' = 123) UNION' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME like '%SomeColumnName%'
--You may want to filter on data type here.  Did I leave anything out?
AND c.data_type IN ('BIGINT', 'INT', 'TINYINT', 'SMALLINT', 'NUMBER', 'DECIMAL', 'MONEY')

SELECT @Tsql = LEFT(@Tsql, LEN(@Tsql) - 7)

PRINT @Tsql

--EXEC sp_executesql @Tsql
```

Comment: Hmph. I'm trying this. The first select, ie the first 8 lines are returning nothing. Fwiw, the column of interest is an int

Comment: The printed @Tsql command should be one or more select statements.  Each statement will be two "lines", appended with `UNION`.  Highlight one of those select statements (without the `UNION`) and run it.  What happens?  If nothing is returned, then it is an "empty result set".