# MS SQL Select case query true or false then execute another SELECT query

Tags: sql, case, sql-server-2014

Hey all I am trying to figure out a way to send **2 result tables** from the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN EXISTS 
  (
      SELECT name FROM usersTbl WHERE name = 'Bob Barker' 
  ) 
  THEN 'TRUE'
  ELSE 'FALSE'
END AS result1

|result1  |
|---------|
| TRUE    |
```

Now that query above works just fine. However, I am needing it to **execute another select statement** if its **'TRUE'** like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN EXISTS 
  (
      SELECT * FROM usersTbl WHERE name = 'Bob Barker' 
  ) 
  THEN 'TRUE'
      (SELECT name FROM usersTbl WHERE name = 'Bob Barker'
                              AND active = 1) AS result2
  ELSE 'FALSE'
END AS result1

|result1  |
|---------|
| TRUE    |

|result2       |
|--------------|
| Bob Barker   |
```

So instead of having just **result1** return this will allow both **result1 and result2** to be returned.

How can I go about formatting the query like that?

Comment: This makes little sense. How about an edit with sample data and expected output?

Comment: ok i updated the OP

Answer (score 0):

You query looks bit wrong ... it should rather be

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN name = 'Bob Barker' THEN 'TRUE'   ELSE 'FALSE' END AS result1
FROM usersTbl 
WHERE name = 'Bob Barker'
AND active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an odd one, but if you want 2 result sets, you could use `IF EXISTS()`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM usersTbl WHERE name = 'Bob Barker')
BEGIN
    SELECT 'TRUE' as Result1;
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                             FROM usersTbl 
                             WHERE name = 'Bob Barker'
                             AND active = 1)
                THEN (SELECT name
                      FROM usersTbl 
                      WHERE name = 'Bob Barker'
                      AND active = 1)
                ELSE 'FALSE'
                END as Result2;
END
```

If you want to return `FALSE` if the first result doesn't exist, you'll have to add another `IF`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM usersTbl WHERE name = 'Bob Barker')
BEGIN
   SELECT 'FALSE';
END
```

Edit: Full query with final `FALSE`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM usersTbl WHERE name = 'Bob Barker')
BEGIN
    SELECT 'TRUE' as Result1;
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                             FROM usersTbl 
                             WHERE name = 'Bob Barker'
                             AND active = 1)
                THEN (SELECT name
                      FROM usersTbl 
                      WHERE name = 'Bob Barker'
                      AND active = 1)
                ELSE 'FALSE'
                END as Result2;
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM usersTbl WHERE name = 'Bob Barker')
BEGIN
   SELECT 'FALSE' as Result1;
END
```

Comment: can you go ahead and combine the FALSE as well in the original example please?

Comment: @StealthRT Done.  If you run that whole block, it will either return 2 result sets (`TRUE, Bob Barker`) or one result set `FALSE`.  If, in the latter case, you want 2 `FALSE` result sets, just duplicate the `SELECT FALSE;`

Comment: It gives no output. It just says **Command(s) completed successfully.**

Comment: @StealthRT Did you run the whole thing or only the second part?

Comment: the whole thing using your **Edit: Full query with final FALSE:**

Comment: @StealthRT Hm.. that should be impossible.  I will go ahead and make a SQLFiddle.

Comment: @StealthRT I removed the `;` for SqlFiddle, but that should not cause an issue in SSMS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147860/discussion-between-aaron-dietz-and-stealthrt).

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM subTable1
WHERE
    st.value = 'Value'
    AND st.restrictiveValue = 'restrictiveValue'
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) AS resultCount FROM subTable1 st WHERE st.value = 'Value') != 0

SELECT COUNT(*) AS resultCount FROM subTable1 st WHERE st.value = 'Value'
```

If you don't want it to return an empty table, you may want to look into using dynamic SQL as mentioned in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811964/dont-display-empty-return-sets)